# How mule api manager manage spring boot based service?

Tags: spring-boot, mule, microservices

I've created a spring boot based service and like to deploy it to existing mule API platform, then I realize there are some challenges I need to face by myself such as, service discovery and policy management.

To be specific, I want to know if there is any way to manage policy for spring boot service from mule API manager? Since there is no agent that mule service has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight forward way is to proxy your custom API by generating a proxy in the Anypoint API Manager. 
Deploy that proxy application on a Mule server in CloudHub or on a runtime on-premise.
Then you have your Spring Boot Application API under control and can apply policies, see analytics, etc.

[MuleSoft Doc on API Proxy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/setting-up-an-api-proxy)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @brazo